# How can I get a running total of my observable sequence?

Tags: c#, system.reactive

I am taking an observable from Joseph Albahari:

```
IObservable<int> GetHeartBeat()
{
    return Observable.Create<int>((observer, cancelToken) => this.Start(observer, cancelToken));
}

async Task Start(IObserver<int> observer, CancellationToken cancelToken)
{
    int beat = 0;
    var random = new Random();
    while (beat < 10)
    {
        await Task.Delay(random.Next(500) + 700, cancelToken);
        observer.OnNext(beat);
        beat++;
    }
}
```

and then I run this:

```
var observable = this.GetHeartBeat()
    .TimeInterval()
    .Buffer(3, 1)
    .Select(l => l.Average(x => 60 / x.Interval.TotalSeconds));
observable
    .Select(i => string.Format("{0}, ", i))
    .Concat(observable.Count().Select(i => string.Format("{0}", i)))
    .Subscribe(i => System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(i));
observable.Wait();
```

I expect to see this:

```
71.9889864709428, 1
72.9592264002639, 2
67.6743699542054, 3
```

etc.

but I am seeing this:

```
71.9889864709428, 
72.9592264002639, 
67.6743699542054,
```

How deeply wrong can I be right about now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need this:

```
var observable = this.GetHeartBeat()
    .TimeInterval()
    .Buffer(3, 1)
    .Select((l, i) => string.Format("{0}, {1}", l.Average(x => 60 / x.Interval.TotalSeconds), i))
    .Subscribe(i => System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(i));
```

Comment: ah, the Linq way out ;)

Answer (score 1):

The standard approach to getting a running total with Rx is to use the `Scan` operator.